# Xquery dont "filter" the first TAG with attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

Im noob with xquery and I'm "testing" codes

Is impossible for me filter one xml in concrete.
Im not sure, but seem a problem with the first TAG, that contains an attribute and, probably, I'm parsing wrong...

XML Sample

```
<findToFileResponse xmlns="xmlapi_1.0">
        <equipment.PhysicalPort>
                <mtuValue>9728</mtuValue>
                <userLabel>RIOXXXX</userLabel>
        <displayedName>Port 1/1</displayedName>
        <siteId>10.10.10.1</siteId>
        <siteName>LO0015P1</siteName>
        <children-Set>
            <ethernetequipment.EthernetPortSpecifics>
                <actualDuplex>fd1000</actualDuplex>
                <children-Set></children-Set>
            </ethernetequipment.EthernetPortSpecifics>
        </children-Set>
    </equipment.PhysicalPort>
    <equipment.PhysicalPort>
        <mtuValue>9728</mtuValue>
        <userLabel>RIOXXXX</userLabel>
        <displayedName>Port 1/2</displayedName>
        <siteId>10.10.10.10</siteId>
        <siteName>LO0015P1</siteName>
        <children-Set>
            <ethernetequipment.EthernetPortSpecifics>
                <actualDuplex>fd1000</actualDuplex>
                <children-Set></children-Set>
            </ethernetequipment.EthernetPortSpecifics>
        </children-Set>
    </equipment.PhysicalPort>
</findToFileResponse>
```

For example, this xquery (Im testing, the objetive is join with other xml with the same first TAG):

```
let $docu1 := doc("ListadoVanos.Mon_Jan_14_040000_CET_2019.xml")/findToFileResponse
return $docu1
```

I expect something like:

```
<equipment.PhysicalPort>
        <mtuValue>9728</mtuValue>
        <userLabel>RIOXXXX</userLabel>
        <displayedName>Port 1/1</displayedName>
        <siteId>10.10.10.1</siteId>
        <siteName>LO0015P1</siteName>
        <children-Set>
            <ethernetequipment.EthernetPortSpecifics>
                <actualDuplex>fd1000</actualDuplex>
                <children-Set></children-Set>
            </ethernetequipment.EthernetPortSpecifics>
        </children-Set>
</equipment.PhysicalPort>
<equipment.PhysicalPort>
...
</equipment.PhysicalPort>
<equipment.PhysicalPort>
...
</equipment.PhysicalPort>

...
```

but answer an empty result

Any idea? can you help me to build this first filter?

Thanks in advance

Im using BaseX. This is the info for that:

```
Compiling:
- pre-evaluate fn:doc(uri) to document-node() item: doc("ListadoVanos.Mon_Jan_14_040000_CET_... -> document-node {"ListadoVanos.Mon_Jan_14_...
- remove unknown element/attribute findToFileResponse
- pre-evaluate iter path to empty sequence: document-node {"ListadoVanos.Mon_Jan_14_... -> ()
- inline $docu1_0
- simplify FLWOR expression: ()
Optimized Query:
()
Query:
let $docu1 := doc("ListadoVanos.Mon_Jan_14_040000_CET_2019.xml")/findToFileResponse return $docu1
Result:
- Hit(s): 0 Items
- Updated: 0 Items
- Printed: 0 b
- Read Locking: ListadoVanos.Mon_Jan_14_040000_CET_2019.xml
- Write Locking: (none)
Timing:
- Parsing: 0.26 ms
- Compiling: 123.72 ms
- Evaluating: 0.17 ms
- Printing: 0.01 ms
- Total Time: 124.17 ms
Query plan:
<QueryPlan compiled="true" updating="false">
  <Empty size="0" type="empty-sequence()"/>
</QueryPlan>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have run into a common problem: selecting XML that is in a namespace. When you select `/findToFileResponse`, you are selecting an element named `findToFileResponse`, but because no namespace prefix is specified, it is assumed that you want to select elements without a namespace, which is common.

However, you can see that your XML document is in a namespace because it uses the [default namespace attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting), which results in itself and all of its descendants being included in that namespace (unless otherwise specified):

```
xmlns="xmlapi_1.0"
```

To select an element in this namespace, you first need to [declare it and assign it to a prefix](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-namespace-declaration) in the XQuery prolog:

```
declare namespace api = "xmlapi_1.0";
```

Now you can select elements in that namespace using the prefix:

```
/api:findToFileResponse
```

You can also select elements in any namespace using the wildcard prefix:

```
/*:findToFileResponse
```